# Need advice with ER diagram

Tags: database, relational-database, entity-relationship

Im starting to learn how to work with database... i had a course in school about 5 years ago and i forgot almost everything. So im starting from 0. I have one project in my mind. A simple storage system for tires at a Vulcanizer(where you go and change tires when winter and summer comes).

So i have in mind 4 tables (client, car, tires, location). I have come up with an er diagram but i have problems with realtion between them. Can you please check if i am good so far? Or would you change something in my case?

[More in picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVII7.png)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your ERD it mostly looks okay apart from the following:

You should have a foreign key `location_id` within your `Tires` table so that you know where the tire is stored. This would mean removing `Tires_TiresID` from your `Location` table. Unless i am misunderstood, the `Client_ClientID` is not-needed in the `location` table. This is because the `location` table should only hold information about the location its self i.e. address, contact details etc.

If I were you, i would do something along the lines of this:[image]

I.E One Customer can have MANY vehicles.
One Vehicle can have MANY tire types. 
One Location can have MANY inventory(tires).
One Tire can be in One Inventory line

Comment: So if i understand correctly i need to remove the relation between client and location tables ? And then reverse the relations between tires and location, so that tires has a foreign key of location ?

Comment: One Customer can have MANY vehicles.
One Vehicle can have MANY tire types.
One Location can have MANY inventory.
One Tire can be in One Inventory.

Comment: Cant seem to get why there is the location inventory between locations and tires.

What i have in mind is that table tires has also a atribute number of tires(its usually 4 because you change all 4 at a time). And location is labled for example: one shelf big enough for 4 tires labled A 1-1... This is why i cant get whats with location inventory

Comment: This will contain which tires are stored at which location.

Comment: But is it ok if i dont have location inventory and only have tires and location. And tires have a foreign key locationID ? And relation between. one set of tires can have only one location

Comment: Think of each `location` as a building (like a warehouse). In order to see whats inside each warehouse you would assign items to the location (using the location_id).

Comment: In this case are locations a warehouse or a Bin?

Comment: Locations are shelfs  :). I will try to see if i understand it now.. and will get back to you when i do :)

Comment: Fair enough, either way, if they are warehouses or shelves it will still work in the same way. I.e. you are mapping inventory to a place(warehouse or shelf).

Comment: One more thing. Shouldnt there be any more relation between customer and tires. How do you form a select statment in your example cant get this... example

select storageid from tires where name "john"....

Comment: For this you would need another table which would create a relationship between which customers purchase/borrow/use a certain set of tires. This table would consist of a PK to identify each transaction, a FK for tire_id and FK for customer_id.

Comment: Ok i give this lcoation and location inventar soem thoughts and i think we missunderstand each other.

Comment: So John comes to change tires on the car from summer tires to winder tires. The summer tires comes of and gets in back room on a shelf labeled J 1/2 . Then the worker sits by computer opens a program and starts writing in it. John/tire model/number of tires/ etc... clicks save and the tires and customer are in database. Next year john comes to change from winter to summer tires. Guy sits by computer types in select location_location from tires where cliend_clientid = john... dont know how  those inqueries works yet :D

here is a picture again:

http://imgur.com/a/hXFwn